# LocalStorage one vs multiple keys

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a performance difference between using one LocalStorage key + encoded items, vs multiple storage keys?

E.G

```
let key = 'ls-key';
let values = {
  v1: [...],
  v2: '...',
  v3: { ...}
}

let encoded = JSON.stringify(values);

window.localStorage.setItem(key, encoded);
```

vs

```
let v1 = [...];
let v2 = '...';
let v3 = { ...};

window.localStorage.setItem(key1, JSON.stringify(v1));
window.localStorage.setItem(key2, JSON.stringify(v2));
window.localStorage.setItem(key3, JSON.stringify(v3));
```

Comment: Not anything significant, but I would strongly prefer the first version, since the `values` all seem to be related. (looking at you, AutoReviewComments...)

Comment: Yes, good point. I also think the first version is "cleaner".

Answer (score 0):

They will both work. Architecturally the second version is better in my opinion, because you can access, modify and remove individual items without having to access everything else.

For example:

```
window.localStorage.removeItem(key2);
```

Instead of:

```
const values = window.localStorage.getItem(key); 

values.splice(1,1);

window.localstorage.setItem(key, values);
```